# SqlCmd: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sqlcmd

Well, I managed to install the SQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS based on the official Microsoft tutorial, step by step. After `sqlcmd` tool installation, when I run

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA
```

and enter the password correctly, I get these two errors:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.

I appreciate any advice on how to get around these unusual errors....

Comment: Seems like an OpenSSL issue. Ubuntu 18.04 provides version 1.1 sql-server wants 1.0 . Found on the related tab at the right side of question;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326908/cant-connect-to-msql-server-after-upgrading-it-on-linux?rq=1

Comment: Adding to the comment @ComputerVersteher, SQL Server is not currently supported on Ubuntu 18.xx. However, the installation is not blocked with the OpenSSL issue described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/installing-sql-server-2017-for-linux-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, what do you suggest me to do to work on SQL in ubuntu?

Comment: Read @DanGuzman link to ms support page and they say "Don't use Ubuntu 18.04" as not supported yet. Ubuntu 16.04 is EOL, so don't use ubuntu. RHEL 7 and SLES 12 are supported  and have EOL 2024.

Comment: Also, see the versions listed under the Supported Platforms section of the [installation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup).

Comment: @DanGuzman as Docker uses Ubuntu 16.04, only RHEL and SLES remain, or not?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, not sure I understand your question but you can run a SQL Server 2017 Ubuntu 16.04 image on a Ubuntu 18.04 host.

Comment: No worries about that, from your side (of course better than 16.04 as host, but a container with an outdated OS hosting a db  is not my dream)? To be safe I won't suggest that, but my knowledge on that is limited.

Comment: This answer would probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61111267/9535070