# ODBC Driver 17 unable to establish connection to MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, debian, odbc, symfony4, sqlsrv

I'm having an issue concerning my Debian 9 server on Apache2, php7.3, ODBC Driver 17, sqlsrv (7.3).
I can't connect it to my Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 running on a Windows Server 2003 R2.

I tried using

```
isql -v -k "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 For SQL Server};Server=SRV-WINDOS\MSSQLSERVER2008;UID=MyUser;PWD=MyPWD;Database=DB
```

on the Debian Server.
Outputs:

```
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

The SQL server seems correctly set-up as I can connect to it with the same Symfony project on my local machine (Windows 10 running Wamp - apache2, php7.2.18, symfony4, doctrine and the sqlsrv extensions).

I also tried using the ODBC Driver 13 but I'm having issues with it,

```
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2' : file not found
```

since it seems like ODBC Driver 13 and lower are not supported on Debian 9`)

ODBC Driver 17 should enable me to establish a connection to my MSSQLSERVER 2008 R2 right ?

**N.B: The Debian 9 server can indeed ping and resolves the domain of the MSSQLSERVER 2008 so it's not a networking issue.**

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was never a ”Windows Server 2005". IIRC, "Windows Server 2003 R2" was followed by "Windows Server 2008".

Comment: Exactly, I reconfirmed and it's indeed `Windows Server 2003 R2`, I'm editing that!

Comment: This answer may simplify everything you needed to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61111267/9535070