Connection errors between PHP and SQL Server in Laravel application
This is my application architecture scenario: Laravel on Azure App Service Linux, PHP + Apache Server, SQL Server database.
We regularly have these types of errors in the Laravel log (about 50-60 entries/day):

production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select top 1 * from [personal_access_tokens] where [personal_access_tokens].[id] = 12706) {"url":"https://example.com/xxxxx?yyyy=dfdf","method":"GET","exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 08001): SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select top 1 * from [personal_access_tokens] where [personal_access_tokens].[id] = XXXXX) at /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:801)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(755): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select top 1 * ...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(424): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select top 1 * ...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2752): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select top 1 * ...', Array, true)
#3 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2740): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#4 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3294): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->Illuminate\Database\Query\{closure}()
#5 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2741): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(735): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#7 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(719): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#8 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php(333): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
#9 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(447): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->first(Array)
#10 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->find('XXXXX')
#11 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2334): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'find', Array)
#12 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2346): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('find', Array)
#13 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/PersonalAccessToken.php(66): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic('find', Array)
#14 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Guard.php(67): Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken::findToken('TQSwiA3Ys68pPeY...')
#15 [internal function]: Laravel\Sanctum\Guard->__invoke(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), NULL)
#16 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/RequestGuard.php(58): call_user_func(Object(Laravel\Sanctum\Guard), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), NULL)
#17 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/GuardHelpers.php(60): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard->user()
#18 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(76): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard->check()
#19 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(55): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->authenticate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#20 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'sanctum')
#21 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(25): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful->Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/Http/Middleware/EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php(26): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#25 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(800): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#28 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(777): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(741): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#30 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(730): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustHosts.php(48): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#48 /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 /home/site/wwwroot/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 {main}

... yes, always on personal_access_tokens table.
After many tests, we discovered that by scaling up the Azure Service Plan from B2 to B3 those errors in the log disappeared, without changing anything else. At no time do we change the database service level. However, I need to know the specific technical issues that cause these database connection errors, since apparently the usage metrics reveal that the B2 service level should be sufficient for resource-level application usage.
Note that the problem is not occurring on every connection, but sporadically.

Post the complete error perhaps? You should have more luck contacting your azure support as well. I wasn't able to find any huge difference between B2 and B3 tiers or how the connection resources are metered out, perhaps you could cache either connections or tokens as well

I haven't had much luck with Azure support, I haven't gotten any conclusive information. On the other hand, I have also thought about caching the accesses to personal_access_tokens, however that does not answer my question or help find the root cause.

PD: what follows the error is nothing more than the stack trace and I consider it to be irrelevant

Well, the error should at least say if it's connection timeout, network server not found or something else. Do you perhaps have some leaking connections? I think a stacktrace is never wrong, but it's up to you

The stack trace is probably more important than the error message since it shows you what ODBC was attempting to do when it raised the duplicate/generic error message. Error code 0x2746 is often related to TLS protocol misconfiguration but it's hard to see how that can apply here since the connection works most of the time. Showing the stack trace might clear that up.

ok guys, here is your full trace :)

This answer explains it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265913/error-tcp-provider-error-code-0x2746-during-the-sql-setup-in-linux-through-te/61111267#61111267 and this is the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265913/error-tcp-provider-error-code-0x2746-during-the-sql-setup-in-linux-through-te

I do not agree, in an Azure App Service we do not have control over the Open SSL version. Furthermore, the problem is not occurring on every connection, but sporadically.
